# Sass --watch . doesn't recognize change and overwrite

Tags: sass

I'm having in issue with the sass --watch . command. I'm on a windows and I installed ruby and then sass according to instructions I found online. Seemed to work fine until I was using the sass --watch . command. When I enter it into the console, it finds the file and says Sass is watching for a change. When I open the file though and edit it, sass doesn't recognize that the file has been changed, and doesn't overwrite to the new file.
Any ideas?

Comment: check you compass config, make sure the `sass-dir` is correctly specified.

Comment: example: https://gist.github.com/nathansmith/1179395

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I actually can't seem to find the config.rb file at all, did I maybe screw up the installation or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initiate compass before you can use `compass watch`.

Do so with:

```
compass create path/to/project/root/dir --sass-dir="path/to/your/sass" --css-dir="path/to/output/sass"
```

You should then have a compass `config.rb` in your project's root directory that looks like:

```
preferred_syntax = :sass
http_path = '/'
css_dir = 'assets/stylesheets'
sass_dir = 'assets/sass'
images_dir = 'assets/images'
javascripts_dir = 'assets/javascripts'
relative_assets = true
line_comments = true
# output_style = :compressed
```

Then from that root directory you should be all set to run, `compass watch`, and have everything in your sass dir compile to your css dir.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. Turns out I didn't even have compass installed, so I installed it and followed the advice and it works perfectly now, thanks again!